# Archivo workflow inválido en GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github-actions

Es mi primera vez usando GitHub Actions y tengo este problema, al momento de subir mis workflows GitHub me da failure en las acciones con la salida:

> Invalid workflow file
> You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 14

Ya revisé la documentación de GitHub y no encuentro que está mal en la sintaxis, y como no da mayor detalles no se que está mal, mi YAML es el siguiente:

```yaml
name: Deploy from tag

concurrency:
  group: deploy-blindo-version
  cancel-in-progress: true

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'

jobs:
  deploy_blindo_version_from_tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: # esta es la línea donde falla la sintaxis
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy-blindo-version.yaml
      with:
        track: internal
        userFraction: 1.0
        inAppUpdatePriority: 5
        secrets: inherit
```

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguro que lo que quieres no es más parecido a ?

```
steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use local my-action
        uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
```

Es que no hay pasos en tu `steps`. Ese diccionario de `uses` posiblemente serviría si hubiese pasos usándolos... peeero no hay `name` de ningún paso en tu yaml

Comment: entonces `- name:` es necesario para crear steps?, adicionalmente me di cuenta que tenía otro error en la sintaxis de `on:` pues puse tag en lugar de push: tags:, agregaré la corrección del on:en la pregunta